# Работа через return python

Tags: python, sqlite3, telethon

Попытаюсь изложить кратко

Работаю с telethon и sqlite3. Мне нужно чтобы функция возвращала результат и вроде бы ничего но есть проблема.

**Приведу пример:**

```
def handling_input(message):

        chat_id = message.chat.id        
        splitwords = message.text.split()
        
        if len(splitwords) == 3:
            msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Обрабатываем ...')
     
        
            surname = splitwords[0]
            name = splitwords[1]
            patronymic = splitwords[2]

            data = func.handlingfullname(fullname=message.text, name=name, surname=surname, patronymic=patronymic)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, data)
```

В этом куске кода обрабатывается информация пользователя, а затем если есть 3 слова запускается функция по поиску заданных параметров пользователя ниже:

```
def handlingfullname(fullname, name, surname, patronymic):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('databases/test.sqlite3')
    c = conn.cursor()

    rows = c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE '%{surname}%'").fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)
        print(len(rows))
        return row #,rows
```

Функция выше ищет данные в таблице sqlite3 и возрващает их, а так же количество строк которое получилось, но есть несколько проблем.

**1. Первый вопрос. Из таблицы видом**

```
('товаровед', '0322218591')

('Суматра ЛТД', '0322218591')

И так далее... (10+ строк)
```

Бот отправляет только первую строку, а не все, в таком формате - товаровед. Просто без ничего, даже без номера, просто первую строку первого столбца. Как это исправить чтобы отправляло все данные полученные из таблицы без скобок и ''.

**2.Второй вопрос**: Как return не только данные таблицы sqlite3 но и количество строк которые образовались, чтобы бот отправил сообщение сколько строк получилось. Как можете заметить то сам код написан, в первой функции - print(len(rows)), но я не знаю как возвратить это значение.

***Если вы дочитали до конца, я уже благодарен, не каждый будет читать массу информации***

Comment: В один вопрос нельзя включать сразу несколько вопросов (по правилам Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В каждом учебнике написано, что `return` ЗАВЕРШАЕТ выполнение функции!!! Все, что написано после первого встреченного `return` - не выполняется!

```
for row in rows:
    print(row)
    print(len(rows))
    return row # как только выполнение доходит до этой строчки, функция завершается.
```

Если нужно вернуть значение `len(rows)`, то нужно и написать `return len(rows)`, а не `print(len(rows))`.

Если нужно вернуть все данные, то нужно написать соответственно, `return rows`, а не создавать ненужный цикл.

Comment: Так то всё понятно. Но цикл создавался чтобы посчитать количество строк и вывести их через return, если делать так как вы сказали без цикла, а просто return rows это не решает проблему, выдает всё так же - только первую строку первого столбца

Comment: Даже в вопросе написано, что количество строк определяется через len(rows)... Так что непонятно, для чего создавался цикл. return rows выдаёт конечно же все сразу, а не только первую строку первого столбца. Если конечно в rows лежит  вся таблица, а не первая строка первого столбца.

Comment: Вот мы и подошли к сути, если написать print(rows) то да, выдаст всю таблицу как нужно, но в боте оно выдает только первую строку первого столбца. bot.send_message(chat_id, data)

Comment: вопрос про строки был в том что, как передать это значение обратно в функцию и возможно даже обозначить как переменную чтобы можно было вставить эту переменную в бот.сэндмэссдж

Comment: попробуйте прочитать еще раз все, что я написал. вы писали return rows в функции? исходя из ваших комментариев - нет.

Comment: Писал конечно же, я не настолько глупый) Иначе бы выдало ошибку что Null

Comment: `def handlingfullname(fullname, name, surname, patronymic):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('databases/test.sqlite3')
    c = conn.cursor()

    rows = c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE '%{surname}%'").fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    
    print(len(rows))
    return rows`

Comment: Если вы про перебор циклом, то это был отчаяный шаг с моей стороны, я до этого не в цикл вставлял return rows и всё так же